# Animated Background not working on mobile

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-animations

I found css for an animated rainbow background online and it works awesome on pc but on mobile it gets cut off and doesn't look good

```
.wrapper { 
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  left:0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
background: linear-gradient(124deg, #ff2400, #e81d1d, #e8b71d, #e3e81d, #1de840, #1ddde8, #2b1de8, #dd00f3, #dd00f3);
background-size: 2000% 2000%;
background-attachment: fixed;

-webkit-animation: rainbow 18s ease infinite;
-z-animation: rainbow 18s ease infinite;
-o-animation: rainbow 18s ease infinite;
  animation: rainbow 18s ease infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rainbow {
    0%{background-position:0% 82%}
    50%{background-position:100% 19%}
    100%{background-position:0% 82%}
}
@-moz-keyframes rainbow {
    0%{background-position:0% 82%}
    50%{background-position:100% 19%}
    100%{background-position:0% 82%}
}
@-o-keyframes rainbow {
    0%{background-position:0% 82%}
    50%{background-position:100% 19%}
    100%{background-position:0% 82%}
}
@keyframes rainbow { 
    0%{background-position:0% 82%}
    50%{background-position:100% 19%}
    100%{background-position:0% 82%}
}
```

Here is what it looks like on my phone[full page view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNiHM.jpg)

[View when it first loads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orPX7.jpg)

edit: When it first loads, the background takes up the full screen but then I can scroll around and it stops just at the edge of the screen. Also, I just surrounded by body in a div class named wrapper

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like a problem with the CSS. This looks more like an issue with the element that has the class `wrapper`.
This element probably doesn't stretch out to occupy the entire width of the page.

There are multiple ways to make sure that the element takes up the entire width of the page. You can try something like:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100vw;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but unfortunately I'm having the same issue